# 401k contributions explanation

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, limits, employer-match

I have a basic question on 401k investment. Below is what my company is matching:

> XYZCompany will match your contributions, up to 4% of your eligible
>   compensation, to a maximum of $10,600.

Now I have couple of questions:

- If I am contributing `4%` into my 401k account then what does it mean?
- If I am contributing `15%` into my 401k account then what does that mean?
- If I am contributing `50$` into my 401k account then what does this mean?

Sorry for asking silly question. Any explanation will help me understand better how to go further and start contributing into my 401k account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your salary is $100K.

*Case 1:* Your company will match up to 4% of your eligible compensation, to the maximum of $10600, which in your case is $4000.

*Case 2:* assume your salary is $1M. Now the company match maximum is $10600, since 4% of your salary is more than that.

The company will **match**, meaning the company will only deposit the same amount you've deposited.

*Deposit case A:* Assume you deposited the maximum $18K (I think that's the maximum this year).

In the first case, the company will match up to 4% of your salary and will deposit $4K on your behalf.

In the second case the company will match up to $10600 and will deposit that amount on your behalf.

*Deposit case B:* Now assume you only deposited $2K to your 401K. Now, in both cases the company will deposit $2K on your behalf, because it only matches your deposit, even if it limits the match by a higher amount.

Comment: I deleted my answer because you said the same thing and got in quicker. One thing I suggest adding/mentioning is that we shouldn't assume OP's employer is matching 100%. It is possible the company matches a lower amount and the OP left that info out.

Comment: I was analyzing the quote provided, from that it sounds like they match 100%. The fact that they discriminate based on salary sounds weird, because this may invalidate the plan.

Comment: Yes they are matching 100%. So basically my company will match only 4% of my salary amount, it doesn't matter how much I am contributing right? let's say if my salary is 160k and if I contribute 20% to 401k then my company will match only 6400 only right? And how much will I be adding further more on top of this?

Comment: Basically I am confuse when I am contributing 20% into my 401k account, what does that mean? And let's say If I don't contribute anything to my 401k account, then company  will still match 4% which is 6400?

Comment: The company will match 100% of $0 in that situation. Which doesn't do you any good. Remember they are matching a percentage (even if it is 100%) of YOUR contribution, not your salary. The salary is only used to calculate the cap on their contribution.

Comment: ok I see, makes sense now. Basically if I am contributing 6400 into my 401k account, then company will also contribute 6400 in my 401k account right given my salary is 160k let's say? So total money end of the year will be `12800` in my 401k account. Am I correct? And secondly if I contributing 4000 in my 401k then company will also contribute 4000 so end of yeear it will be 8000. And third case is, let's say if I am contributing `8000` then company will contribute only 6400 only so total will be `14400` end of year? Am I correct on all three conditions?

Comment: @lining yes, you got it

Comment: cool. Thanks a lot littleadv and JohnFx for making me understand this. Appreciated.